# Pegando dados API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Bom Dia,

Estou pegando dados de uma API e ela me retorno 100 registros por página, entretanto não me informa quantas páginas existem de registro. A única informação que me é passada é é quando não encontra mais dados, conforme exemplo abaixo;

```
{
"retorno": {
    "erros": [
        {
            "erro": {
                "cod": 14,
                "msg": "A informacao desejada nao foi encontrada"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é paginação para ir pegando os dados até a API retornar o erro. Segue abaixo parte do meu código.

```
        $apikey = "{apikey}";
    $outputType = "json";
    $page = 1;
    $url = 'https://site.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=' .$page.  '/' . $outputType;
    $retorno =  $this->executeGetContacts($url, $apikey);
    foreach($retorno as $erro){
        if(isset($erro->erros[0]->erro->cod) == 14){
            echo ('Pedidos cadastrados');
        }else{
            foreach($retorno as $pedidos){
                for($page; $page < count(); $page++)
            }
        }
    }
```

Muito Obrigado

Comment: Versão do Laravel?

Comment: Estou usando a 5.8

Comment: Laravel já tem paginate se quiser coloco um código exemplo

Comment: Não seria paginar. O que eu quero fazer é quando a API que estou pegando os dados, me retornar os 100 registros a variável $page tem que ir incrementando para ir pegando os outros 100 dados da API, até que a API me retorne o código 14 e caia no if

Comment: você pode só passar um limite de dados na query e retorna o tanto certo sem essa volta toda

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de consultas com limite no laravel:

```
Model::limit(10)->get();
```

faça um teste e me avise.

Comment: Lucas. Não posso usar o limit. Estou pegando os dados de uma API. Ela me retorna um json com 100 dados por página. Para pegar mais 100 dados tenho que usar o https://site.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=2/json e assim por diante, até ela me retornar o código 14 (não encontrou mais nenhum dado). O problema que estou tendo é incrementar o page. Ele não passa de 2. Teria que ir incrementando até cair no if